# How to properly use multiple tracking IDs in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

My current setup for `Google Analytics` looks like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I read this article explaining how to track data when using more than 1 tracking ID:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers

So using the examples in the link, I need to add the following lines of script:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-2', 'auto', 'myTracker2');
ga('myTracker2.send', 'pageview');
```

What do I do with `displayfeatures`? Do I need to prepend `myTracker2` to it as well? Something like:

```
ga('myTracker2.require', 'displayfeatures');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as per developer pages:

Using Multiple Trackers

To use the display features plugin with multiple trackers, prepend the require call with the tracker name, as in this example:

```
// create a tracker named 'foo' for property UA-XXXXX-Y
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', {name: 'foo'});
ga('foo.require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('foo.send', 'pageview');

// create a second tracker named 'bar' for a different property UA-XXXX-Z
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Z', {name: 'bar'});
ga('bar.require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('bar.send', 'pageview');
```

Loading the display features plugin for a named tracker will result in the tracker name being appended to the cookie name. The above example would create the cookies _gat_foo and _gat_bar.

Link to source: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/display-features

I hope this helps.